# H1 Tag behind slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have started using slick slider for my project.
I want to add a h1 tag above the slider. I achieved this by creating a h1 tag and then giving it a position absolute. But now the text appears behind the slider. 
Heres my code:

```css
.centered {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;

}

.slick-slide{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh!important;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!--general stuff --> 
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- custom css-->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--custom css-->
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--slider-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slider/slick/slick.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slider/slick/slick-theme.css"/>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="slider-section">
      <h1 class ="centered">test</h1>
      <!--slider -->
      <div class="your-class">
        <div><img src="https://dailypost.files.wordpress.com/2016/06/city.jpeg?w=1200"></div>
        <div><img src="https://dailypost.files.wordpress.com/2016/06/city.jpeg?w=1200"></div>
        <div><img src="https://dailypost.files.wordpress.com/2016/06/city.jpeg?w=1200"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--jQuery-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap js -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!--slick slider-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slider/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <!-- custom js -->
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can find the live demo here:

http://u512656.gluweb.nl/mop/

I tried:

```
.centered {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

z-index

Comment: Add this css .centered { z-index:10;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your custom.css file

> .your-class.slick-initialized.slick-slider {
>       z-index: -1;
>   }

This will put all your content above this slider.

Comment: worked, but isnt this overwriting existing settings? is this a problem or is it fine?

Comment: The original slider css doesn't state anything about z-index so it's totally fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's `h1` that you're referring to?

If so try setting `z-index` on this element as absolute positioned elements create layers.

Comment: I meant H1, and i tried z-index and nothing happened, i will update my question with what i have tried.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the text to appear above the slider you will need to make it a block element and not absolutely positioned.

If you want the text on top of the slider, you can do so by adding another class (or amending .centered) with the following:

```
z-index: 1;
color: #fff; // Something other than black, as the background image is currently black.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add z-index css property to h1 tag.

```
.slider-section h1.centered{
    z-index: 1;//you can keep it any larger value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more sensible solution than adding z-indexes to everything would be to place the H1 tag below the slider in the markup. Then, your absolute positioning will automatically place your H1 in front of your hero. Z-indexing is ok, but it is not necessary here and it tends to stir up confusion as a project grows.